# What's behind the mechanism of Django models and fields?

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

What is the Django/Python mechanism behind the Django model/field part of framework?

To be exact, I am looking for a hint on how Django parses (?) class definition and then knows which fields are required?

```py
from django.db import models


class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    year_of_production = models.DateField(null=True)
    # the rest of fields...
```

I think the same mechanism is behind Django Forms framework or DRF serializers. I checked repos of these projects but I still can't find any reasonable starting point.

There's a architectural problem under my question. I think I need to implement something similar to this mechanism:

```py
class Field:
    def __init__(self, label: str, required: bool = True, **kwargs):
        self.label, self.required = label, required


class CharField(Field):
    def __init__(self, max_length: int, **kwargs):
        self.max_length = max_length
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class DateField(Field):
    ...

class BooleanField(Field):
    ...

class Model:
    # the mechanisms I do not understand

class MyModelInstance(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    # etc.
```

What I need is really simple solution that knows that field is required. But as I stated before I am not that advanced and I would really appreciate any hints.

Edit: I think I'm looking for sth like Django Forms mechanism, not models/fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms and Models follow the same basic idea, but forms are a little simpler, so let's take a tour there.

[The `DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass` metaclass](https://github.com/django/django/blob/24e8f7f7d3063a3bbfe14774080bc89035b4a3e2/django/forms/forms.py#L25-L53) is used on [`Form`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/24e8f7f7d3063a3bbfe14774080bc89035b4a3e2/django/forms/forms.py#L495).
It gathers up the `field`s at declaration time (with some MRO walking, but the basic idea is to just see if they're `isinstance(x, Field)`), removes them from the concrete class declaration and moves them into `cls.base_fields` (where `cls` is the class you're declaring).

When you instantiate this new `Form` of yours, [this code over here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/24e8f7f7d3063a3bbfe14774080bc89035b4a3e2/django/forms/forms.py#L85-L90) deepcopies `self.base_fields` (which is on the class level, but that's beside the point) into `self.fields` (so you can safely modify `self.fields` within each form instance without affecting others across requests.

That's basically it, really.

Beyond that, if you wanted a thing that gathered required fields on a separate attribute, that'd just be something like

```py
cls.required_fields = {f for f in cls.base_fields if f.required}
```